# Hyperref package not working with latest version of the memoir class

Tags: hyperref, memoir

I use the latest version of the `memoir` class:

```
Document Class: memoir 2021/06/16 v3.7p configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
```

and the latest version of the `hyperref` package:

```
Package: hyperref 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hypertext links for LaTeX
```

The documentation mentions that it should be all fine, however I still don't have any kind of link anywhere in the document (not only the TOC).

Any help would be appreciated. The configuration looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,final,extrafontsizes,draft]{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linktoc=all,
}
```

Comment: Show a complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: I can't say for sure without a proper example, but it might be the (global) `draft` option. For `hyperref` the option `draft` disables all hyperlinking. If you need hyperlinks and the `draft` option for `memoir` you can pass `final` to `hyperref` to counter the global/class option `draft`.

Comment: @moewe I must admit that I failed to remember that, this was indeed the issue. At least that made me update `memoir` and `hyperref` to avoid another issue...

Comment: Please don't answer the question in the question. Instead post an answer and accept it.

Comment: I agree in general, however in this specific case I don't think that adds anything. Feel free to post your own answer then. This question is dumb and I could also remove it altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (global) class option `draft` that you are passing to `memoir` is picked up by `hyperref`. For `hyperref` the `draft` option disables all hyperlinking.

There are two ways to fix this

1. Don't load the `draft` option at all.
2. If you need the `draft` option for the class and/or other packages, counter the `draft` option only for `hyperref` by passing `final` to it.